# Upload new object to CloudFront. Curl show the file changed but the browsers don't

Tags: curl, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to understand this weird behaviour.
I've a web distribution list on CloudFront which takes files from S3.
I've set in CF the

```
Minimum TTL: max-age=15
```

and I can see the max age value also in the page header with curl

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 851
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:48:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:48:01 GMT
ETag: "6f05a132c76b8e482f8f72f3cd2aa2b1"
Cache-Control: max-age=15
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 dba4881aee9ac99f5dba4dcd7e8175b1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 8Cwu-1UPFb2BL03mvu3exf17UzWqCZVrUGvNtc2xCeVg47G1UnqVjg==
```

Once I uploaded the new html page which contain my changes, if I curl the resource I can see the page changed.
If I open the page with Firefox/Chrome the page doesn't changed and the max-age value is not respected since the age value in the header is around 32000

```
date    : Thu, 16 Nov 2017 17:23:41 GMT
etag    :"8ad74acb5563f12bfd239683a3d96d75"
cache-control:15
server  :AmazonS3
age :31029
x-cache :Hit from cloudfront
via :1.1 1d3fdb2bba223d815ff2e40453…8.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id :ooeDeSw-_ZpMDR25_yN9VhfyJF2FeAgiklzE5QZusNRs_glDqobgcg==
```

What else I missed from or did I not consider?

Answer (score 1):

Changing an object in S3 does not push it to CloudFront if it's already cached there, as this one is... from 31029 seconds before you made the request.

```
age :31029
```

To evict objects from the CloudFront cache (forcing CloudFront to make a new request from the origin the next time the object is requested) requires an [invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html).

Note also that Minimum TTL has no real meaning, here, since that is the *minimum* `max-age` or `s-maxage` that CloudFront will respect when it initially caches the object.  It only does anything when the object has a maximum lifetime that is shorter than the minimum, and it is most likely of no consequence once an object is cached.